# How to correctly unwrap `data` inside `data`?

Tags: purescript

I’m trying to access nested data (`Foo.y` inside `Bar` in the example below), but the straightforward approaches for unwrapping `Foo` inside `Bar` that come to mind do not work. But how to unwrap it correctly?

Here my data:

```
module Foo where

import Prelude

data Foo = Foo { y :: Int }

data Bar = Bar { x   :: Int
               , foo :: Foo }
```

The following (of course) does not compile, error is `Could not match type { y :: Int } with type Foo` — just like `Bar`, `Foo` needs unwrapping first:

```
fn1 :: Bar -> Int
fn1 (Bar { x, foo }) = x + foo.y
```

So I put up my hopes for the following, but alas, compiler says “no” (parentheses around `Foo` constructor don’t help):

```
fn2 :: Bar -> Int
fn2 (Bar { x, Foo { y } }) = x + y

fn3 :: Bar -> Int
fn3 (Bar { x, Foo f }) = x + f.y
```

The following works, using a helper function to do the unwrapping, but there has got to be a better way:

```
getY (Foo foo) = foo -- helper function

fn4 :: Bar -> Int
fn4 (Bar { x, foo }) = let foo2 = getY foo in
                       x + foo2.y
```

So, how do I do nested “unwrap”?

[EDIT]

After an hour or two of trying things out, I came up with this, which works:

```
fn5 :: Bar -> Int
fn5 (Bar { x, foo = (Foo f) }) = x + f.y
```

Is this the idiomatic way to do it? Why don’t `fn2` and `fn3` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions *fn2* and *fn3* do not work because the compiler does not know which record field you are referring to (*foo*). You have to reference record fields by name.

Function *fn4* is a perfectly fine solution (although your naming is pretty confusing, *getY* actually returns the wrapped record inside the *Foo* constructor, not the *y* value).

As far as I can tell, *fn5* is the shortest possible solution. I would personally prefer a helper function (like in your fourth example):

```
getY :: Foo -> Int
getY (Foo rec) = rec.y

fn6 :: Bar -> Int
fn6 (Bar { x, foo }) = x + getY foo
```

Comment: OK, makes sense: it’s not by _position_, but by _name_ — just clicked for me, thanks. And thus my `getY` should be called `getFoo` or be written the way you wrote it. FWIW, I wasn’t looking for the shortest solution  but one where I can see the destructuring in the pattern. Now, how can I get at the `y` straight from the pattern?

Comment: Like this: fn7 (Bar { x, foo = Foo { y } }) = x + y

Comment: Also, note that { field } is syntactic sugar for { field: field }.